# How to sort subdir glob by filename, not full relative path

Tags: shell, zsh, filenames, sort

Given a tree of files like this:

```
subdirFoo/2019-06-01-blah.ext
subdirFoo/2019-06-07-blah.ext
subdirFoo/2019-05-02-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-06-03-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-05-05-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-05-13-blah.ext
```

I want to iterate over these files and pass them as arguments to `somecommand`, BUT, I want to iterate over them in sorted order by the FILENAMES, not the full paths.

Normally, globs are sorted alphabetically, but I get them in this order:

```
subdirBar/2019-05-05-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-05-13-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-06-03-blah.ext
subdirFoo/2019-05-02-blah.ext
subdirFoo/2019-06-01-blah.ext
subdirFoo/2019-06-07-blah.ext
```

meaning to say, the subdirectories are considered in the sorting, which is not what I want.

How can I get the glob to be sorted by filename only, but still keep the subdir in the loop so that the command can reference the file correctly?  i.e. stripping off the subdir won't work because then the path to the file is incorrect/lost.

i.e. I need them in this order:

```
subdirFoo/2019-05-02-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-05-05-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-05-13-blah.ext
subdirFoo/2019-06-01-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-06-03-blah.ext
subdirFoo/2019-06-07-blah.ext
```

Solution in zsh preferred, but I can accept bash or sh.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` you will need to set the field delimiter to `/`, and sort on the 2nd field.

Comment: Right, something like `printf '%s\n' fileglob* | sort -k2 -d/ | xargs somecommand`, and hope theres no newlines in the fnames. (I assumed -d for delimiter, not at my terminal rn)

Comment: The `sort` in gnu coreutils has a -z option. It uses the nul character as the record delimiter. And `-0` for `xargs`. nul is not used in filenames.

Comment: Perfect: i couldn’t remember if sort would do that or not, so I stayed away from it. Obviously preferable

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the *right* way to do it, but you could stuff a `${VAR##*/}` parameter substitution inside a `zsh` `oe` glob qualifier:

```
 % printf '%s\n' subdir*/*(.Noe:'REPLY=${REPLY##*/}':)
subdirFoo/2019-05-02-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-05-05-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-05-13-blah.ext
subdirFoo/2019-06-01-blah.ext
subdirBar/2019-06-03-blah.ext
subdirFoo/2019-06-07-blah.ext
```

This orders the result of the glob by the last path component (the filenames). The `:'...':` bit in the glob qualifier is executed for each match, and `REPLY` is set to a value that will be used as the sorting key (`$REPLY` is the actual match from the start).

See for example the *Glob Qualifiers* subsection of [zsh: 14.7 Filename Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion)

> oe and o+ are special cases; they are each followed by shell code,
>   delimited as for the e glob qualifier and the + glob qualifier
>   respectively (see above). The code is executed for each matched file
>   with the parameter REPLY set to the name of the file on entry and
>   globsort appended to zsh_eval_context. The code should modify the
>   parameter REPLY in some fashion. On return, the value of the parameter
>   is used instead of the file name as the string on which to sort.
>   Unlike other sort operators, oe and o+ may be repeated, but note that
>   the maximum number of sort operators of any kind that may appear in
>   any glob expression is 12.

Comment: Yes, this is similar to what was suggested to me for one of my questions, but the intent was a bit different: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551160/returning-randomised-items-from-glob-match

Comment: Okay, this does seem to work, but holy guacamole, how is anyone supposed to remember the syntax of such a monstrosity?  :)  EDIT: Actually, this doesn't work.  It still sorts by subdir first before sorting on filename.

Comment: @Pistos Like everything, by using it. It's actually quite simple once you get used to it. The `(...)` modifies the behaviour of the globbing pattern, the `.` selects only regular files, the `N` acts as `nullglob` in `bash`, and `o` orders the result according to some criteria. The criteria here is `e` which means "execute the following code for each match and use whatever is left in `REPLY` as the sorting key for that match".  The two `:` are delimiters for the code to execute.

Comment: @Pistos steeldriver's command works, and is the correct solution for the `zsh` shell (it graciously handles any type of filename, which `sort` does not, unless you use GNU options). If you tested it with `ls`, know that `ls` does its own sorting. If you wish to use `ls`, make sure it doesn't sort: `ls -f`

Comment: @Kusalananda : I didn't use `ls`, I did this: `printf '%s\n' {somedir,someotherdir}/someprefix*.sql(.Noe:'REPLY=${REPLY##*/}':)` and it put all the files of somedir together, followed by all the files of someotherdir.

Comment: @Pistos Ah, yes. The brace expansion would expand to two patterns, one after the other. Those two patterns would then be expanded to generate two separate lists, each separately sorted. This is why you don't get the wanted effect. Better then to use `(somedir|someotherdir)` in place of that brace expansion.

Comment: Yes!  Changing to `(...|...)` syntax indeed gave the right results.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using `find` instead of globs.  Thanks to @ctrl-alt-delor for the hint about sorting by field.

```
for file in `find {subdirFoo,subdirBar} -maxdepth 1 -name 'prefix*.ext' | sort -t / -k 2`; do echo $file; somecommand $file; done
```